# Padding Not Showing?

Tags: css, wordpress, padding

[On this page](http://www.glamourunderground.com/fitness/), the text under the photos in the main section (a.event) isn't showing the 5px padding top and bottom. Any ideas why? Thanks guys =)

```
a.event {
width:315px;
height:auto;
border:0;
padding: 5px 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your a tag is wrapping around the image *and* the text. So the padding appears above the image and below the text.

Firebug is a good tool for inspecting the HTML that's being rendered. It makes it trivial to find these kinds of errors.

Comment: p.s. I voted to close this question because it's too localised - it's not generally applicable outside your particular circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

wrap the text with `<p>...</p>`

then in your css:

```
a.event p {
padding: 5px 0;
}
```